# WKWebView didFinish is not working Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I am loading a url in WKWebView.

```
let url = URL(string: "myURL")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView1.navigationDelegate = self as! WKNavigationDelegate
webView1.load(request)
```

But, the delegate function,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)")
}
```

not trigger when it complete load.

Then I use KVO for the web view

```
webView1.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   if (keyPath == "loading") {
       guard var web1 = object as? WKWebView else { return }
   }
}
```

Loading is working fine.  But, is there any `observer` available for after load the `webview`

Comment: Please find updated answer

Answer (score 18):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)
```

must called if you set `navigationDelegate` properly.

Have you done this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

}
```

if you set the above `WKNavigationDelegate`, your code will be like this,

```
let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.load(request)
```

and delegate method,

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     print("Finished navigating to url \(String(describing: webView.url))")
}
```

Hope this helps, let me know in case of any queries.

FYI. No need to set external observers.

**UPDATE**

Enable `App Transport Security` in your `info.plist` like this?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Yes, my webview is conforming the WKNavigationDelegate delegate

Comment: then it must work, have you set it like this class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, please show your code

Comment: Now it is working, with any url like google.com . But, I am trying to load a http://ipaddress/video/mjpg.cgi this is not working

Comment: Please paste full url

Comment: it is a mpeg video url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167537/discussion-between-ppl-and-vineesh-tp).

Comment: My guess is the problem is that you're accessing a cgi link, it isn't going to fire an HTML document loading event

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem because my `navigationDelegate (WKNavigationDelegate)` was disposed because of zero reference count. So `print` in `deinit` helped me to figure out the problem and to solve it.
Note: Be sure that you have at least one strong reference to delegate.