# Why not able to navigate from WKWebView delegate method "didFinish" in swift

Tags: swift, url, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I am showing CCavenue Url in web page and my all `WKWebView` delegate methods are called but the thing is I'm unable to navigate to another viewcontroller from `didFinish` method

**code:** here am presenting CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC like this

```
    let vc = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC, storyboardName: .Miscellaneous) as! CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC
            
     vc.studentId = myId
     vc.modalPresentationStyle =  .pageSheet
     self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

**and here is the code for CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC** when i print then i got print also but unable to go to MyFollowersViewController why? where am i wrong. please guide me

> inside the condition

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    loadRequestOnWebView()
}

private func loadRequestOnWebView(){
    
    var apiUrl = "https://project.in/dev/api/student/workshop-payment-initiate-new?workshop_id="
    
    let myURL = URL(string: apiUrl)
    var myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myRequest.httpMethod = "post"
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}

@IBAction func backNavigationButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("finish to load")
    
    if let urlAsString = webView.url?.absoluteString{
        let redirectURL = "https://k12studio.in/dev/payment-success"
        
        if urlAsString.contains(redirectURL)  {
            
            print("inside the condition")
            let vc = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .MyFollowersViewController, storyboardName: .Miscellaneous) as! MyFollowersViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: may be page is still loading... some scripts are there... try to use `shouldStartLoadWith`

Comment: or may be this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73290443/1066828

Comment: @FahimParkar I didn't get this `shouldStartLoadWith ` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot push a ViewController over a presented ViewController. What you need is to attach a UINavigationController to your
**CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC**

Try this:

```
let vc = Helper.getVcObject(vcName: .CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC, storyboardName: .Miscellaneous) as! CCAvenuePaymentWebviewVC
vc.studentId = myId
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: better is to dismiss payment vc and in completion do the navigation using original navigation... you are creating new which will create another navigation controller which is not good because he will have issue if he want to go to popToRootVC...